# Looking for a USB GSM modem, compatible with Solaris 10 (sparc)

Tags: usb, solaris-10

Seven months on SF, and my first question.  I do hope someone has an answer, as I'm at my wits' end.

I have a Nokia 6310i connected via RS232 cable to a Solaris 10 system, for sending SMS messages from NAGIOS using [smstools3](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/).  It works fairly well, but over time people have started to really enjoy the convenience of SMS notification, and the number of messages sent has crept up from 2-3 a day to 30-100 a day, and the GSM phone solution isn't really up to that: every few days it goes unresponsive, starts failing to send messages, etc.  My inclination is to get a GSM modem and use that instead, but there are no longer any RS232 GSM modems that I can find, so I have to use a USB one instead.  Solaris' documentation is poor on precision about which USB modems it can talk to; it says all modems that honour "Universal Serial Bus Communication Device Class Abstract Control Model (USB CDC ACM) specification" are OK, but I can't find a single modem manufacturer who knows anything about that spec.

I would value **any** recommendations, positive or negative, anyone can make about USB GSM modems on Solaris; SMS-related recommendations are extra-useful, but I'm keen to know anything.  Failing that, recommendations for Linux-compatible ones would be useful, as it's **somewhere** to start.

Thanks for any light anyone can shed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's getting "too localized" here, but anyway:

http://www.coniugo.com/ still offer RS232-capable GSM modems. I bought a USB version from [Conrad](http://www.conrad.com), and I guess they ship to the UK.

Beside that, maybe it's possible to use a web based SMS service for your normal notifications and use the Nokia exclusively for Nagios notifications (so Nagios  will reach you when the network is down).

Comment: Thanks for that, Sven.  I should have made it clear that **all** my SMS notifications are NAGIOS-related ones, and thus need to go out via a direct-attach device.  My users loved being "in touch" with the state of their apps much more than I had expected them to.  I will investigate your other pointers immediately!

Comment: Conrad have a UK arm, conrad-uk.com, and I have ordered one of the quadband GSM modems from them.  I'll try to remember to come back and update this question with confirmation that it works in practice, but I figure that you've satisfied the criteria for an ACCEPT - thank you!

Comment: Just as a follow-up, I got a Coniugo GSM modem, and it works brilliantly.  If anyone else does this, do remember that they need an external power supply **and** an external antenna (mine had an MMCX connector) to work.