# Nagios Alerts / Notifications - SMS

Tags: performance-monitoring, network-monitoring, nagios

Configured Nagios core 4.0 and NDOutil 2.0 both are working in ubuntu.

Now i am looking for alert types in Nagios.

And i am confused in plug-ins and Add-ons in nagios.

Especially i am looking in sms alerts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do email-to-SMS via one of the commercial gateways, or send the SMSs directly from your NAGIOS box via GSM-enabled hardware.

There are many commercial email-to-SMS gateways, they are often country-specific, and we don't do service recommendations here on SF, so I won't try to give one.  The upside of this is it's easy to do and requires no upfront investment; the downside is that there are a whole long chain of things that can go wrong to stop your SMSs getting out, including failure of your internet connection, DNS problems, mail server issues, and so on.

Or you can directly-attach a GSM modem to your NAGIOS box and use (eg) smstools3 and an SMS-friendly SIM to send SMSs directly from NAGIOS.  Again, equipment recommendations are off-topic for SF these days, but you may find [the answer to one of my old questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/266092/looking-for-a-usb-gsm-modem-compatible-with-solaris-10-sparc) (which would probably, and rightly, get closed these days) to be of some use here.  The downside of this method is that it requires investment in equipment as well as payment for a service, but the upside is that as long as the monitoring server doesn't lose power, it can probably get alerts out no matter what else goes wrong at your site.

In both cases you will probably need to tailor custom alerts to fit useful information into a single SMS.

Comment: Awesome MadHatter ... 

Thanks. can you help on sending sms alerts through sms gateways and suggest me if you know any links regarding sms gateways and smpp.

Comment: Sivashanmugam, I'm not going to do that for the same reason you've been gathering downvotes above: you clearly haven't done any research here.  SF is intended for professional sysadmin questions, and "*please teach me the basics of this tool*" isn't a professional-level question.  I thought a request for a pointer was a reasonable question, so I've pointed you in the right direction.  But we're not here to hold your hand every step of the way; you need to go and read some HOWTOs, try a few setups, and learn for yourself.  If, along the way, you have more **specific** questions, then ask them!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking to integrate SMS gateways with Nagios, a free alternative would be something like [Cloud Alert](https://cloudalert.cloud/), which has a command line thats easier to setup. It isn't SMS though - you need to install an app to receive the alerts. (Disclosure: I work for Cloud Alert)